# Cannot invoke createOptionsSet(int) on the array type OptionSet[] error when calling protected creation method from one class in another

Tags: java, protected

I've created a class Auto that contains an OptionSet array class (ie Color), which connects to an OptionSet class that contains an Options array inner class(ie Blue, Red). The OptionSet and Options methods are all protected, so I'm creating an instance of Auto that can use the existing methods while reading in a file. While the Auto class' createOption method below works (it chains to the OptionSet method createOption), the createOptionsSet method does not. I'm getting the error 'Cannot invoke createOptionsSet(int) on the array type OptionSet[]'. Yet this seems to be exactly what I'm doing in the createOption method. What is it that's different for this method?

The Automotive.java class:

```
package model;

import model.OptionSet;

public class Automotive {

    //variables
    private String name;
    private static float basePrice;
    private OptionSet[] opSet;

    //constructor
    public Automotive(int size, String n) {
        opSet = new OptionSet[size];
        name = n;
    }

    public void createOptionsSet(int opSetSize) {
        this.opSet.createOptionsSet(opSetSize);     
    }

    public void createOption(int opSetLocation, int size) {
        this.opSet[opSetLocation].createOption(size);

    }
    //more getters and setters
}
```

And here is the OptionSet.java class:

```
    package model;

    import model.OptionSet;

    public class OptionSet {

    //variables
    private OptionSet[] opSet;
    private Option opt[];
    private String name;

    //constructor
    protected OptionSet(String n, int size) {
        opt = new Option[size];
        name = n;
    }

    //methods
    protected void createOptionsSet(int size) {
        OptionSet[] opSet = new OptionSet[size];   //creates OptionSet array
    }

    protected void createOption(int size) {
        this.opt = new Option[size];
    }

    //inner class Option
    protected class Option{
        private String name;
        private float price;

        Option(String name, float price){
            name = name;
            price = price;
        }

        protected void createOption(String name, float price){
            Option opt = new Option(name, price);

            //more getters and setters
        }
    }
```

Comment: `opSet` is an array, making `this.opSet.createOptionsSet(opSetSize);` an illegal operation. You need to invoke a method on an element, not an array.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. In that case, how can I get around this to actually create the optionSet? I'm not sure what element to use when the only existing part at this point is the opSet object.

Comment: Wouldn't you just initialize `this.opSet` with a new array of size `opSetSize`?

Comment: I think that will be fine, yeah. Just couldn't get my brain to jump to that as an answer. Thank you!